# MongoDB return object only if status true from another collection (with paginate)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i.m using this plugin of mongoose:

```
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
```

And i have a collection named accounts, it have a person_id field.

I have another collection person with have status.

What i'm trying to do is search only accounts having status: true from person.

The problem is: i'm using paginate, so i can't map the results because the paginate'll go wrong.

```
accounts: [],
    "totalDocs": 3,
    "limit": 4,
    "totalPages": 37,
    "page": 3,
    "pagingCounter": 9,
    "hasPrevPage": true,
    "hasNextPage": true,
    "prevPage": 2,
    "nextPage": 4
},
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why you should not create your own pagination?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, so ..i tried but i need to retrieve too many result from first search..
Let me say first search at accounts result was 40,
the second at person this result was gone to 10.. but there's more than 10 at person.. so i cannot perform a true limit.

Comment: I think you should to open `mongoose-paginate-v2` in your `node_modulels`. It's a open source right? The logic in there, you can learn from that code and make your own code to fix this issue.